# Similiarity between two corpus of text

Tags: r, data-mining, text-mining, cosine-similarity

I have two separated corpus of text, and i would like to understand wheter these are similiar or not using cosine similarity.
I'm not sure on how to approach this problem, but i was thinking as a solution to compute the Document-Term-Matrix for each corpus and calculate the cosine similiarity for these DTM.

Is this approach correct ? How can I write a function to calculate cosine similiarity between to matrices ?

Comment: Are you open to using a library rather than writing your own code? R has a library "quanteda" that has this built-in.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Thanks for the suggestion, even better if a library can handle this